# Where was the Buenos Aires - Lima Spanish Royal Road?

Tags: transportation, spanish-empire, south-america, argentina

the Royal Road was a designation assigned to any road administered by the Spanish Crown, including through its viceroys. During the Spanish Empire, several such roads ran through the expanses of Central and South America (as well as California). A famous example is the 966km long [* California Mission Trail*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Camino_Real_%28California%29) connecting [Mission San Diego de Alcalá](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_San_Diego_de_Alcal%C3%A1) to [Mission San Francisco Solano](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_San_Francisco_Solano_%28California%29).

One of these roads connected Buenos Aires to Lima. What is the course of this route? Is there any map depicting its path? I couldn't find any image or map that covers the road nor basic information about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seemed to follow the bright red path depicted in this image:

[image]

The [Incan Empire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inca_Empire) had built and maintained a very [extensive road transport system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inca_road_system) prior to their [conquest by Spain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_conquest_of_the_Inca_Empire). Segments of the old roads were converted into, and subsequently expanded upon, to form this particular [*El Camino Real*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Camino_Real).